# How to break/stop sequence if exception occurs in mediator using WSO2 ESB

Tags: jms, wso2, wso2-esb

i am trying to implement logic that if during execution of sequence any error occurs, like e.g JMS endpoint is invalid, So sequence should drop here and log the message.

The actual mediation is like below:

Validate-->Clone-->Log   Clone mediation snapshot attached.[image]

My Service Code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="AdapterService"
       transports="jms"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full" separator="..... XML Received..."/>
         <validate source="//DOCUMENT03">
            <schema key="conf:/DOCUMENT03_CUSTOM.xsd"/>
            <on-fail>
               <makefault version="pox">
                  <reason value="Invalid XML"/>
                  <detail>Error while validating  XML at  Adapter Service.</detail>
               </makefault>
               <log level="full" category="ERROR" separator="... XML Error..."/>
               <drop/>
            </on-fail>
         </validate>
         <clone>
            <target>
               <sequence>
                  <script language="js">mc.getEnvelope().getBody().getFirstElement().getFirstElement().getFirstElement().detach();</script>
                  <log level="full"/>
                  <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                  <send>
                     <endpoint>
                        <address uri=**"jms:/BookingMessage?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://1929.168.1.113:61616&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue"**
                                 format="pox">
                           <timeout>
                              <duration>10</duration>
                              <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                           </timeout>
                           <suspendOnFailure>
                              <errorCodes>101507,101505,101503</errorCodes>
                              <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                              <maximumDuration>10</maximumDuration>
                           </suspendOnFailure>
                           <markForSuspension>
                              <errorCodes>101508,101504</errorCodes>
                              <retriesBeforeSuspension>5</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                              <retryDelay>10</retryDelay>
                           </markForSuspension>
                        </address>
                     </endpoint>
                  </send>
                  <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                     <format>
                        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                           <soapenv:Body>$1</soapenv:Body>
                        </soapenv:Envelope>
                     </format>
                     <args>
                        <arg xmlns:tns="http://com.sanomalearning/cdm/finance/generalledger/v1"
                             evaluator="xml"
                             expression="//DOCUMENT03/CMMHeader"/>
                     </args>
                  </payloadFactory>
                  <log level="full"/>
                  <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                  <send>
                     <endpoint key="conf:/CMMHeaderQueueUrl"/>
                  </send>
                  <log level="full" separator="Message Sent to Queue"/>
               </sequence>
            </target>
         </clone>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence>
         <log level="custom" separator=",">
            <property name="text" value="***FAult Handler***"/>
         </log>
         <property name="SET_ROLLBACK_ONLY" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
         <drop/>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="text" value="An unexpected error occured"/>
            <property name="message" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
            <property name="code" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
            <property name="detail" expression="get-property('ERROR_DETAIL')"/>
            <property name="exception" expression="get-property('ERROR_EXCEPTION')"/>
         </log>
         <drop/>
      </faultSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
      <rules>
         <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
         <default>application/xml</default>
      </rules>
   </parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactory">myQueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.DestinationType">queue</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">AdapterService.01.Request.Queue</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Now when i execute this service after receiving request from queue, it is not sending message to invalid queue but sending message to second Url. Now i want if message is not sent to invalid endpoint then sequence should dropped. The invalid url is Bold.

Comment: isn't that what fault sequence does?

Comment: I would recommend you to get rid of the clone mediator and try the same scenario to make sure this is not a special case issue with clone mediator. Whats the requirement to use the clone mediator here?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can not define two send mediators under the same target in one clone mediator instead you have to define those inside two different targets.

Also would be helpful if you can elaborate your requirement a bit more. For a solution with regard to JMS endpoint is invalid issue what you can do is define a drop mediator inside the fault sequence.